# Issues with ForceBindIP on Windows 7 (x64)

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, 64-bit

I am desperately needing a solution to binding certain applications to specific network interfaces. ForceBindIP seems to be my only solution. Although the website claims it works up to XP, Google says that many users running 7 have had it work successfully. I have UAC disabled, yet still:
[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening? If not, does anyone know a viable alternative to ForceBindIP? I'm a gamer and I'm addictively trying to torrent on a secondary connection while playing games online.

Comment: uTorrent has a settings option to bind it to a specific IP. You don't need a tool for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two errors are because `ForceBindIP` is not on your path. If you copy it into System32 or into another folder on your path, you wont' have that issue.

The third error is because the "Program Files (X86)" folder has spaces in the name. You need to enclose the path of the executable in double-quotes because it contains spaces - `"C:\Program Files (x86)\uTorrent\uTorrent.exe"`

Also, if you go into the advanced settings dialog of uTorrent, you can simply specify what IP or interface it should bind to.

Comment: Thanks guys. All I see in uTorrent is how net.bind_ip. If I put a network interface GUID there, will that also work? Is there anything else I need to change?

Comment: @Craig I don't know if that works with a GUID. It does work with an IP though.

Comment: Does anyone know if ForceBindIP makes a permanent bind, or only until you close that application?

Comment: @Craig it's only until you close that application.

Answer (score 0):

You should copy 2 files to the directory:

x86bit: C:\Windows\System32\ and for x64bit: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\

Comment: What files?  As it stands, this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Make a shortcut, go to properties, then add the `forcebindip` command in the target box like:

```
C:\Windows\System32\ForceBindIP.exe -i 10.0.0.10 "C:\Users\Media Pc\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

This is the only way I have found it to work.

Comment: oh he meant the two forcebind files you downloaded

Comment: You might want to mention in your answer where the `ForceBindIP.exe` file needs to be located.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here http://bit.ly/2gdEMMG

Just copy Forcebind files in SysWOW64 folder in windows folder 
and make a shortcut and copy and paste this line in it:

forcebindip -i 192.168.43.242 “C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla firefox\firefox.exe”

Just change the IP numbers and application path