# Any way to specify which Internet connection to use on a Mac?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac, wired-networking

I am currently connected to both an Ethernet and Wi-Fi connection (different networks.) Is there a way I can tell my web browser to use one connection and another web browser to use the other?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/181882/force-an-application-to-use-a-specific-network-interface may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. You can set the order for all applications though: System Preferences > Network > Little gear icon > Set Service Order…